# ts.plot() not plotting Time Series data against custom x-axis

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am having issues with trying to plot some Time Series data; namely, trying to plot the date (increments in months) against a real number (which represents price).

I can plot the data with just `plot(months, mydata)` with no issue, but its in a scatter plot format.

However, when I try the same with `ts.plot` i.e. `tsplot(months, mydata)`, I get the following error:

`Error in .cbind.ts(list(...), .makeNamesTs(...), dframe = dframe, union = TRUE) : no time series supplied`

I tried to bypass this by doing `tsplot(ts(months, mydata))`, but with this I get a straight linear line (which I know isn't correct).

I have made sure that both `months` and `mydata` have the same length

EDIT: *What I mean by custom x-axis*

I need the data to be in monthly increments (specifically from 03/1998 to 02/2018) - so I ran the following in R:

```
d <- seq(as.Date("1998-03-01"), as.Date("2018-02-01"), "day")
months <- seq(min(d), max(d), "month")
```

Now that I have attained the monthly increments, I need the above variable, `months`, to act as the x-axis for the Time Series plot (perhaps more accurately, the time index).

Comment: In the question title you say *custom x-axis*. Can you explain this a bit better?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hi, of course - I have updated the question to clarify what I mean by custom x-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With package `zoo` you can do the following.

```
library(zoo)

z <- zoo(mydata, order.by = months)

labs <- seq(min(index(z)), max(index(z)), length.out = 10)
plot(z, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = labs, labels = format(labs, "%m/%Y"))
```

**Data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)

d <- seq(as.Date("1998-03-01"), as.Date("2018-02-01"), "day")
months <- seq(min(d), max(d), "month")

n <- length(months)
mydata <- cumsum(rnorm(n))
```